# Object vs. var [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, json, api, object, var

I have a problem with understanding how to refer to the object that I receive by fetching the API. Having

```
var data [{"id": "7150", "employee_name": "Julia", "employee_salary" = "39999"}]
```

in the JS file, I can easily refer to a variable and, for example, sort it (data.sort ((a, b))

But.. What if I have in my code

```
return fetch (url).then (function (resp) {
         return resp.json ()
}
.then (data => {
     data.forEach (result => {
        ....
        })
   })
```

Is data invisible outside "then"?
How can I refer to my api data outside "then"?

Comment: Which `then` are you querying the scope of

Comment: `data` is simply a local variable that is available when the callback function is called. You could set a higher scoped variable to `data` for use afterwards.

Comment: You would at that point save `data` as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

Your data is being loaded asynchronously. Oftentimes in complex apps, the data would be stored in some sort of "bucket". It might be service, or it might be a data store. There are many libraries for this, it depends on the framework being used.

If you are just starting out, you don't need any of that. You can make your own simple data bucket with a global variable. Global variables are dangerous for various reasons, but for learning purposes they get the job done.

```
window.globalDataBucket = {};


return fetch (url).then (function (resp) {
         return resp.json ()
}
.then (data => {
     data.forEach (result => {
          globalDataBucket.fetchResult = result;
          // Now you can use the data in window.globalDataBucket.fetchResult anywhere.
        })
   })
```

With this in place, you can access your data from anywhere in the app, because it is now globally scoped. However, it's up to you to add checks or polling that ensure that code that relies on this data is only run after the data is loaded.